# convert some lines of php statement into ternary operator

Tags: php, ternary-operator

This is my first time in learning ternary operator. What I am trying to do here is to convert some lines of php statement into ternary operator. Can anyone please help me to check if what I am doing here is correct. And how to echo it. Thanks.

```
 <?php
      $tmp = 'this.ppt';
      $tail = array_pop(explode('.',$tmp)); //'{file}'
      $allow = array('ppt','pdf','docx');
         if (in_array($tail, $allow) {
             $type = $tail;
         } 
         elseif ($tail == 'doc') {
             $type = 'docx';
         } 
         else {
             $type = 'img';
         }
     echo $type;
 ?>
```

TP

```
  $tail = ($type == $tail ? 'ppt','pdf','docx' : ($type == 'doc') ? 'docx' : 'img()'))
```

Comment: Your original code: 1. is readable 2. works 3. easy to maintain. Your new attempt: neither of 3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not quite there. This is the equivalent of your if / elseif / else as a single line:

```
$tmp = 'this.ppt';
$tail = array_pop(explode('.',$tmp)); //'{file}'
$allow = array('ppt','pdf','docx');
$type = (in_array($tail, $allow) ? $tail : ($tail == 'doc' ? 'docx' : 'img'));
```

However I question your idea to use a ternary operator hear. As @zerkms pointed out your original code is more legible and it works fine.

Comment: Okay, this is the best answer I got from here. It makes it clear how to make ternary operator (Yeah, because there is a time where the team asked me to use this) Thanks.